# how to get 3d touch app icon haptic feedback similar to peek or pop in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, 3dtouch

Generally I want to get the haptic feedback that is produced when an icon is force pressed (peek/pop) within my SpriteKit game. Currently I am using 3d touch in the following way

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        if touch.force > CGFloat(6.66) {
        shootOut ()
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the haptic feedback (similar to a peek or pop) to occur when `if touch.force > CGFloat(6.66)` condition is satisfied. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The peek/pop haptic feedback can be done with `UIPreviewInteraction` in iOS 10. (The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipreviewinteraction) for that are rather incomplete, but they also talk about it in a [WWDC16 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/228).) This class is new in iOS 10, but works on both iPhone 6s and iPhone 7.

However, the idea with the peek/pop haptic feedback is that it should be tied to a UI that's doing something conceptually similar to peek/pop. (Even if that's a custom UI that can't get peek/pop haptics "for free".) [Just like on Apple Watch](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/human-interface-guidelines/interactions/#haptic-feedback), each haptic on iPhone has a meaning, and those meanings are more clear when you use them for the purposes they're designed for. (On the other hand, using `UIPreviewInteraction` means that the system automatically handles for you the correlation between touch force and when to produce a haptic.)

So if you're looking for more general-purpose haptic feedback, in iOS 10 there's also a separate API for that, which provides several different kinds of haptics for use in a wider variety of situations. Check the docs for [`UIFeedbackGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifeedbackgenerator) and play around with the options it provides and maybe you'll find one that feels right for your game.

`UIFeedbackGenerator` requires both iOS 10 and iPhone 7 — it's specifically for the richer vocabulary of haptic signals available in the newer device's second-generation Taptic Engine, so it has no effect when used on iPhone 6s.

Comment: "so you only get that same haptic if you're actually peeking/popping a view controller" Not so. UIPreviewInteraction gives you that kind of response with no view controller in the story (and that is the point of it, as they tell you in the WWDC 2016 video on this topic).

Comment: D'oh. Forgot about that one. :) Nonetheless, HI guidelines advise against using that for anything but peek/pop — it's just separated from the peek/pop UI so that custom UIs that create similar interactions can use the same feedback. Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: "Nonetheless, HI guidelines advise against using that for anything but peek/pop" That's not how I understand it, and it's not how I understand what they showed in the WWDC video.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for UIPreviewInteraction and UIPreviewInteractionDelegate. Basically, it's a gesture recognizer for force touch. (Why they didn't actually *make* it a gesture recognizer beats me.) I've got an [example](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch05p208forceTouchGesture2/ForceTouchGesture/ViewController.swift) of a force-touch based "game" where the user pops "bubbles" using force touch. This shows how you can measure and respond to the amount of force as a gesture.

Answer (score 1):

```
if touch.force > CGFloat(6.66) {
```

You might want to use touch.maximumPossibleForce instead of hardcoded constant:

```
touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce
```

It's also might be a good idea to check whether force touch available or not:

```
if(is3dTouchAvailable(traitCollection: self.view!.traitCollection)) {
   //...
}
```

More details and code sample http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/02/01/swift-how-to-use-3d-touch-introduction/

As for the exact same "effect" as for the icon force touch, here it is:

```
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
generator.prepare()

generator.impactOccurred()
```

See more details about checking support and fallback for the haptic feedback:
http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/01/29/haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator/

Answer (score 0):

To get haptic feedback in your game you can use these

`UIImpactFeedbackGenerator`

`UINotificationFeedbackGenerator`

`UISelectionFeedbackGenerator`

e.g

```
// Impact 
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
generator.impactOccurred()
generator.prepare() // prepare for next time, should ideally call this before playing first time as well

// Selection
let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
generator.selectionChanged()
generator.prepare() // prepare for next time, should ideally call this before playing first time as well

// Notification
let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
generator.notificationOccurred(.warning)
generator.prepare() // prepare for next time, should ideally call this before playing first time as well
```

Just play around with all the generators and settings and see whats best for you.

Hope this helps